# Extract specific information from string in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Little backstory first. I got a script that downloads and opens a .csv file and reads the content. The part of the script i got a problem with is below.

```
file = Download_Folder + str(attachment)
print (file + " is active")
file = open(file, 'r')
for line in file:
 if "WOD" in line:
  print(WOD)
```

The problem I got is that every line is between 500 - 1000 characters and I only want the script to return some of them. I can't use slicing since the numbers of characters before and after my information is different for every line. Below is an example line.

```
2020-01-15 07:05:59 CET;ORD007_PickListReport;'7000009569 7000009494 7000009867 7000009364 7000009808 7000009260;Finished;WOD0200115070558117;884ee259-f2ba-48c6-8ef8-39fc6e48805b
```

I want the script to find 3 characters ("WOD") in the line string and print them and the 16 characters after. Then go and scan the next line in a loop.

Comment: Use str.find to get the index of "WOD" and then use slicing

Comment: are you familiar with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)? You can define a pattern and search for that pattern in each line

Comment: Read about [module-csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I don't see any specific problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the string index() method:

```
for line in file:
    try:
        index = line.index("WOD", 0, len(line))
        print(line[index:(index + 17)])
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: This will raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found. [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)